# How to format my result for 2 decimals digits after comma

Tags: sql, format, decimal

I'm kind new to SQL world and just started doing queries.

In this case, I'm calculating how much % a number represents of that other number.

This is how I'm doing:

Percentage = ROUND(((NULLIF(SUM(value_1), 0)) / NULLIF(SUM(value_2),0) * 100), 2),

Even if I use ROUND(), the results still the same, they will give me 6 digits after comma:

100.020000

56.800000

-33.330000

100.000000

42.490000

Is there any way to format these numbers with just 2 digits after comma?

Thank you!

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use sql server, you can convert your result :

```
Percentage = Convert(numeric(10, 2), ROUND(((NULLIF(SUM(value_1), 0)) / NULLIF(SUM(value_2),0) * 100), 2))
```

Or Cast it :

```
Percentage = Cast(ROUND(((NULLIF(SUM(value_1), 0)) / NULLIF(SUM(value_2),0) * 100), 2) AS numeric(10, 2))
```

Comment: It worked just fine with the Convert(). Thank you very much! 
I've tried Cast(... AS DECIMAL(10,2)) but I got an error though I didn't try with numeric.

Thank you man!